# Dash Input, Output Component Property

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Referring to documentation link as below:-

[dash-plotly](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks)

In the documentation,  `component_property` for the `Input` & `Output` `callback` is explained that:-

> In Dash, the inputs and outputs of our application are simply the
> properties of a particular component. In this example, our input is
> the "value" property of the component that has the ID "my-input". Our
> output is the "children" property of the component with the ID
> "my-output

However in example code copied below, I can't find the `component_property` of `value` or `children` in the html skeleton. It is noted from the documentation that the `children` is omitted.

**Q:** how do I know if I have to specify `value` , `children` or some other `component_property`?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H6("Change the value in the text box to see callbacks in action!"),
    html.Div(["Input: ",
              dcc.Input(id='my-input', value='initial value', type='text')]),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='my-output'),

])


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='my-input', component_property='value')
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'Output: {}'.format(input_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know whether you have to explicitly give a specific `component_property` when using a component, you will have to look at the documentation of that component. It should tell you which properties are mandatory and which are optional.

For most components, the majority of properties is optional. Look at the documentation for `html.Div` [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/div) for example. Sadly, this example also shows that the documentation is not always complete on this, as the properties `n_clicks`  and `n_clicks_timestamp` are also optional but not listed so as of now. That makes all properties of the `html.Div` optional.

In practice, you will mostly explicitly list only the properties that you want to set to some initial value. If you should be missing any mandatory ones, Dash will throw an Exception.

Note that you can use any property as `Input` / `Output` / `State` of a callback, regardless of whether they are optional or not. They will exist with some default value even if you did not name them explicitly.

Regarding the example you gave, the `component_property` `value` is actually explicitly given in this line, you might have overlooked it:

```
dcc.Input(id='my-input', value='initial value', type='text')]),
```

It's the second argument to `dcc.Input`. The `children` property of the `Output` component is indeed not explicitly given in the layout. I added two working alternatives that include it below:

```
html.Div(id='my-output'),                # from the given example
# html.Div(children=[], id='my-output'), # explicitly give children property
# html.Div([], id='my-output'),          # name of the children argument may be dropped if it goes first
```

Note how the third way is also the one used in the other two `html.Div`s in your example.